# How can a client privately query a subset of a database?

Tags: encryption, oblivious-transfer, private-set-intersection, pir

I am trying to build a solution for the following problem and I think it is relevant to crypto:

Party A has a set of indexes M, such as a group of people's ID; Party B has information of a larger group of people, and we name the set of this group as N. Let's assume M is a subset of N. Party B agrees to provide information of people whoever requested by A for a business purpose. Although party A wants to have all the information of M from B, it does not want to reveal any ID in M to Party B during the process.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **PIR, Private Information Retrieval** or **OT, Oblivious Transfer** and possibly also **PSI, Private Set Intersection**.

PIR enables a client to query a server for the $i$-th entry of a database without the server learning the query. However, the client may learn values for other indices too.

OT is a stronger PIR without this leak.

PSI enables a client to find the intersection of their secret set and the server's secret set. You might want to do PSI before PIR to filter out non-members before trying to look them up, to reduce communication costs. Possibly of interest [RePSI, Reactive PSI](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/344) reduces the ability for a malicious client to enumerate the server's set.

---

A much weaker alternative may be of interest too. If the database is large, but reasonably partitioned and the client is willing to reveal which region they are querying, then you can use k-anonymity.

[Ex. Have I Been Pwned's password lookup](https://www.troyhunt.com/ive-just-launched-pwned-passwords-version-2/#cloudflareprivacyandkanonymity) works by taking the first 5 hex characters of the hash of your password to identify the partition of the large password hash database. Then, you filter the smaller but still large partition down to your exact hash/key and read its value.

Although the server does not learn the user's password, related queries can uniquely identify the user if they have multiple compromised passwords tied to a common username or email address. I.e. There may be only one user whose two password hashes start with "12345" and "abcde".

If the client searches for the information on "Bobby Smith" and "Carol Smith" and these two people exist in separate partitions, then the server may link the two queries to recover your query. Even if all queries are independent without any relation, k-anonymity still reveals the tiny subset of the large database, the client is interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will look into these topics.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach I propose for this problem is the following:

1. Part A requests all the content from part B (e.g. a json file);
2. Once Part A is in possession of N, then part A can filter and take a smaller subset from N;
3. Finally, Part A just has to put the filtered subset into M.

Comment: You just described the trivial implementation of a PIR. This may suffice, but considering the need to ask the question, it is likely N is too large for all clients to download or the server may wish to rate limit how many entries a client is allowed to query.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, Moises. Just as cypherfox said, N is a very large set. And the final goal is not just get M but also feature information that associates with each ID in M. If I use this method, I'd have to move the whole database to A, which is  impossible. But maybe a possible way is to make up another set M', which is much smaller than N, but larger enough than M. So that M is subset of M'. Then Party A requests information of M' from B, and B does not know which IDs belong to M. It's not a perfect solution, but I will se if it meets the requirement.

Comment: @cypherfox, I really appreciate your point about  PIR, OT and PSI. Have you got another idea for an upgrade to my trrivial PIR approach?

Comment: @S. Luo I'm liking this subject. How are you thinking to perform this M' creation?

Comment: @S.Luo If Alice adds a random sampling to her query, while making the full query public to the server, the server still learns a LOT of information. If Alice asks for "Bobby Smith" and "Carol Smith", then despite the random noise, Bob may notice link the queries and distinguish them from random. Worse, if Alice performs two queries containing the same base set with different random sets, the randomness cancels out and Bob learns the base query. If it is reasonable for the client to leak some information to the server, then see my updated answer.

Comment: @MoisésFerreira There aren't any simple upgrades to the trivial case which maintain its information theoretic security. There are many methods to implement a PIR. There are two major categories. S-PIR, using multiple servers (which may use primitives as simple as xor) and C-PIR, using computationally hard problems (usually Diffie-Hellman, though there are lattice works too). There are also hybrid solutions. PIR aside, k-anonymity is an option for some use cases if the client is willing to reveal some information to the server. See my updated answer for that.

Comment: S-PIR has the potential for information theoretic security; whereas C-PIR cannot. The hybrid solutions benefit from the computational worst case and information theoretic best case. The former relies on cryptography resisting attacks and the latter relies on trusting a threshold of the servers.

Comment: Er, sorry. Not S-PIR, IT-PIR. Information Theoretic PIR.

Comment: That's a very helpful summary, thumbs up for @cypherfox! Using multiple servers is not an option in my work, so I probably will focus on C-RIP or k-anonymity. I believe there's some tolerance for revealing part of the ID information.

Comment: *C-PIR. If you use k-anonymity; use a hash function over the client's name or ID/index, do not use the index directly as that leaks when the entry was added, whereas the hash prefix leaks only the partition.

Comment: (For any moderators. Could you please move these messages to a -chat- and link that chat on both of these answers. Thank you.)

Comment: @cypherfox I'll read about all these approaches. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Luo, if a client performs a query with any kind of filter, the server can find out the specific ID intentded by the client among the subset unless it is quite large to perform a brute force in case of using that specific ID on behalf  of a server unpolite purpose. Sorry, I don't trust in any servers :)

Comment: @MoisésFerreira The only "kind of filter" relevant above, which the server may see, is the partition index when querying a k-anonymous database - this safety strongly depends on the usage (see the unique user identification attack above). If you don't trust the server with anything (except availability and cooperation), then you want PIR. If the server doesn't trust you, it may prefer OT combined with evidence you have the authority to query the entry. ;)

Comment: @cypherfox that's great. Ty.